# Skype problems, "Wrong architecture 'i386' " what is wrong?

Tags: skype

So i recently bought Samsung Chromebook (http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/chrome-os-devices/XE303C12-A01US) this one, and because the chrome OS system doesn't support the Skype program I decided to change to Ubuntu. But now I'm still having problems installing it, I have been trying for 2 days now and felt like it was time to ask for help.

Answer (score 4):

Short: You won't be able to run Skype on that machine.

Reason: Your Chromebooks' processor uses the ARM architecture, and I guess you're trying to install Skype for Intel architectures (x86).

Problem: IIRC Microsoft does not build Skype for ARM (except for Android, but that's another story).

Comment: ohh that sucks, well thanks for the answer anyways!